# How to Batch Export Visible layers / layers in a preset using PyGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I would like to save all layers that are part of a preset in QGIS to an external folder using Python

I have got the following code from another question

```
from qgis.core import *

suffix = "_Test_save"
pathToFile = "C:/Users/david/Desktop/Batch Vector Save testing Python/"

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()

for layer in layers:
    newName = layer.name() + suffix + ".shp"
    ret = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, pathToFile + newName, "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
    if ret == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print newName + " saved to " + pathToFile + "!"
```

This saves all layers in the workspace to my chosen folder but I cannot figure a way to save only the visible layers or even just ones attached to a preset.

This is working code for QGIS2.18 but if possible I would like a solution for QGIS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preset collections have been renamed and bundled into the [QgsMapThemeCollection class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapThemeCollection.html) so for QGIS 3, you could use something like the following which saves all visible layers of a theme to your desired output directory:

```
suffix = "_Test_save"
pathToFile = "C:/Users/david/Desktop/Batch Vector Save testing Python/"

layer_list = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection().mapThemeVisibleLayers(u'theme_Name')
for layer in layer_list:
    newName = layer.name() + suffix + ".shp"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, pathToFile + newName, "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
```